# Blogger API We're sorry, but the value for field labels was not valid

Tags: api, blogger

When I submit the following json format article to blogger

```
{
    "title": "Title",
    "content": "Content",
    "labels":["adventviures", "3ds", "game", "nintendo", "bgr", "metroid", "to", "fox", "Balrog", "bgr", "avi", "review", "addicted", "pikmin", "balrog", "bngr", "bgra", "eshop", "new 3ds", "star", "pokemon", "balrogthemaster", "mario", "thoughts", "on"]
}
```

I get the following error message

```
"error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid",
                "message": "We're sorry, but the value for field labels was not valid."
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "We're sorry, but the value for field labels was not valid."
    }
```

Some other labels do not work

```
1."labels":["CauBeNguNgo","Xe Đua","GTA 5","Thành Trung Gaming","Xe Lamborghini","siêu xe đua","game offline","Cris Devil GamerGame Offline"]
2."labels":["Google israel","Google","entertainment","YouTube Japan 公式チャンネル","YTMA","YouTube","Science & Technology","エンタメ","entame","Awards","YouTube Japan","Music"]}
```

I would like to know if the blogger's labels comply with the rules, I do not find it

Please help me

Comment: Have you tried this method with a lesser number of labels? Blogger has a limitation of 20 unique labels per post

Comment: Great suggestion thank you, I succeeded

Comment: I have updated the label template, not working.Please see my help